# Annotation to load spring component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

We can use `@Import` to load spring configuration. Do we have some annotation to load component directly, without using configuration.

we are using spring boot, but don't want that jar to be auto scanned. I want an annotation where I can load the component. One option is that we import the configuration in that annotation like the below given example, which will load the component. But I wanted to avoid configuration if there is a way to import component directly.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Import(ConfigurationA.class)
public @interface EnableConfigurationA {
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider a solution with the `@ComponentScan` annotation and some filters to include/exclude your classes.